# How do I get django to tell me where I am inside my code

Tags: django

I am starting to us logging in my django project at the moment (on step at a time) and I was wondering if there was a way to put where I am in my code into the error message using python. I.e. If I am in `something.views.something_view` how do I get this class/function location to then tag it onto `logging.error("something went wrong in "+???)`?

Comment: logging `tracebacks` usually helps with that..

Comment: do the tracebacks show up in the logs be default?

Comment: Nope, a good way is to create a logging middleware and log tracebacks in `process_exception` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the logging at application level (in settings.py) using a dictionary, in this way:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)s] [%(asctime)s] [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOGS_DIR, 'application.log'),
            'maxBytes': 5242880, # 5MB
            'backupCount': 10,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'com.mysite': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

The line:

```
'format': '[%(levelname)s] [%(asctime)s] [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
```

will produce a log output like:

```
[DEBUG] [11/Aug/2013 12:34:43] [com.mysite.apps.myapp.middleware.MyMiddleware:28] My log message
```

where:

```
com.mysite.apps.myapp.middleware.MyMiddleware
```

is the class that has logged your message and :28 the line in your code.
A logger is configured in this way at module-level:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in this way, your logger will automatically be resolved using the fully qualified class name!

Comment: Are you sure the line: `'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'` is right? I'm getting `ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named RequireDebugFalse`

Comment: yes! Form the docs "This filter is used as follows in the default LOGGING configuration to ensure that the AdminEmailHandler only sends error emails to admins when DEBUG is False:" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Comment: Yeah. I know why I can't use it. I'm still on 1.3 :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#module-logging), which comes with Python 2.3

You must set a proper formatter for your logger to obtain what you want, so you must set ,

```
import logging
my_logger = logging.getLogger('my_first_logger')
my_logger.setLevel('INFO')  # You can check docs for more info about levels
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(process)d %(threadName)s %(module)s:%(lineno)d %(funcName)s() %(message)s\n\n\n"  # You set your logger debug information here. Check docs for detailed info about what information you can log
filename = 'logs/my_first_log.log'
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename, mode='a')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
my_logger.addHandler(handler)
)
```

And usage:

```
import logging
my_log = logging.getLogger('my_first_logger')

my_log.info('Your log goes here...)
```

Output will be like:

> 2013-08-12 12:43:34,070 INFO my_code_file 26924 MainThread my_module:72 myFunc() Your log goes here...

Update: I forgot to add `FileHandler` file setter. I fixed that. You must do this for each log file you will use. If you will log your all activity into a single log file. Then you need to set the logger object only once. then you will just import it and use it. If you have more than one log file, You must set each log file seperately, then you can use it anywhere you want with:

```
my_log = logging.getLogger('my_first_logger')
my_log.info('Blah blah blah...')
```

Comment: Wooh! Do I have to do that at the top of all my `views.py`?

Answer (score 0):

The python [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module should give you the information you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Logger also has the option to log the line numebers where the log call is made. You need to add %(lineno)d to your formatter. But to log arbitrary line numbers you can try  something on the lines of:

```
import inspect
info = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())
lineno = info.lineno
print info
print lineno
```

**Edit:**

Got the context after seeing alecxe's comment. YOu can either use process_exception middleware or django signal got_request_exception 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#got-request-exception
logger.exception() will log the stack trace for you